# Applications of Multidimensional array search

Tags: search, multidimensional-array

I found a [blog](https://iq.opengenus.org/applications-of-binary-search/) mentions various applications of binary search. I wonder what applications of performing the search operation in multidimensional arrays could be??

I tried to check some potential applications of multidimensional array search on internet but found none.

Thanks so much. Any help on this is hghly appreciated!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.